# How can I solve a forward-backward-looking recurrence system?

Tags: difference-equations

I would like to (numerically) solve a forward-backward looking recurrence equation in *Mathematica*. The system is something like:

```
x[n+1] = x[n] + y[n]

y[n]   = 2* y[n+1]
```

subject to

```
x[0]=1,y[N]=1
```

The problem is that the boundary of `x` at the beginning (`n=0`) where the boundary of `y` is at the end (`n=N`) (hence forward-backward looking). The *Mathematica* command `RecurrenceTable` does not handle this.

I would need to obtain a result for an arbitrary level of `n`. Numerical results are fine. What would be the most efficient method to tackle this problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I must be missing something, this example is easily solved directly:

```
ClearAll[nn, x, y]
nn = 10
x[n_] := x[n - 1] + y[n - 1]
y[n_] := 2 y[n + 1]
x[0] = 1
y[nn] = 1
Table[{x[i], y[i]}, {i, 0, nn}] // MatrixForm
```

[image]

maybe the real problem is more interesting..?

Answer (score 6):

Fairly starightforward approach: Using [`RSolve[]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/RSolve.html)

```
RSolve[{x[n + 1] == x[n] + y[n], y[n] == 2*y[n + 1], x[0] == 1, 
    y[N] == 1}, {x[n], y[n]}, n]
```

Result:

> $\left\{\left\{x(n)\to 2^{-n} \left(2^{n+N+1}+2^n-2^{N+1}\right), y(n)\to 2^{N-n}\right\}\right\}$

As for numerically solving the system: [`NSolve[]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/NSolve.html)

Still, not an elegant .. erm .. "solution", but a start

```
NSolve[{x[n + 1] == x[n] + y[n], y[n] == 2*y[n + 1], x[0] == 1, 
     y[N] == 1}]
```

> $\{\{x(0)\to 1.\, -\text{1.9472683003151566$\grave{ }$*${}^{\wedge}$-174} y(n),x(n)\to 0.517777\, -0.732998 y(n),x(n+1)\to 0.267002 y(n)+0.517777,y(n+1)\to 0.5 y(n),\:
> y(N)\to 1.\}\}$

Comment: Thanks!The NSolve solution sounds like the one I need (I am solving a more complex system and I doubt RSolve can help me). How can I convert the answer to numerical solitions in the form: x[0]=1,x[1]=...,x[2]=...  etc?

Comment: I think that `NSolve` is not doing what you think it is doing. It's treating `x[n]`, `x[n+1]` etc as independent variables and just giving you a random solution to the underdetermined system.

Answer (score 3):

I made a package that deals with the problem. I share it below:

```
BeginPackage["GlobalSystemSolve`"]

GlobalSystemSolve::usage =
        "Globally solves a system of equations. 
Input = {system,variables,boundaries,N}. 
Example:
variables=Function[n,{x[n],y[n]}]
boundaries=Function[N,{x[1]\[Equal]10,y[N]\[Equal]1}]
system=Function[n,{x[n+1]==x[n]+y[n],y[n]==2*y[n+1]}]
N=3"

Begin["`Private`"]


varlist[variables_,N_]:=Flatten[Table[variables[n],{n,N}]]

globalsystem[system_,boundaries_,N_]:=Flatten[{Table[system[n,N],{n,N-1}],boundaries[N]}]

GlobalSystemSolve[system_,variables_,boundaries_,N_]:=NSolve[globalsystem[system,boundaries,N],varlist[variables,N]]

End[ ]

EndPackage[ ]
```

Comment: The brute force approach - I like it :-) By the way, it's not a good idea to use important system functions (such as `N`) as variable names.

Comment: @Simon It seems we agree on most things *Mathematica* but on this one I take exception.  You said variable names and that is true, but Breugem did not use `N` as a variable.  Instead he used it as a pattern name, and it may be *confusing* to do so I don't believe it will cause any problems.  Of course if you use `N` in the RHS you better mean it to be the argument not the function, but that's up to the programmer to manage.  Personally I have taken to using capital letters for pattern names where I feel they are appropriate, though admittedly not `N` that I can recall.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, you're right of course. There's no actual problem with using `N` like that (except that it might cause one to receive unwarranted comments on Q&A websites...)